# I need to parse the content of collection in some other collection in different datatypes in java

Tags: java

```
public static <T extends Collection<? extends Object>,E extends Collection<? super Number>> void parseCollection(T src, E  dest, Class<?> clazz){
        for (Object obj : src) {
            if(clazz.equals(Long.class)){
                dest.add(Long.valueOf(obj.toString()));
            }else if(clazz.equals(Integer.class)){
                dest.add(Integer.valueOf(obj.toString()));
            }
        }
    }
```

When I call this fuction with `Set<String>` as src  and  `List<Long>` as dest
Its showing a compile time exception saying : **"*Bound mismatch: The generic method parseCollection(T, E, Class) of type GenericMethods is not applicable for the arguments (Set, List, Class). The inferred type List is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter >*"**

Function has been called something like this :

```
Set<String> src = new HashSet<String>();
        src.add("1");
        src.add("2");
        src.add("3");
        src.add("4");

        List<Long> dest = new ArrayList<Long>();
        parseCollection(src, dest, Long.class);// exception
        System.out.println(dest);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to rewrite your conversion method like so:

```
public static <E extends Number> void parseCollection(Collection<?> src, Collection<E> dest, Class<E> clazz){
    for (Object obj : src) {
        if(clazz.equals(Long.class)){
            dest.add((E) Long.valueOf(obj.toString()));
        }else if(clazz.equals(Integer.class)){
            dest.add((E) Integer.valueOf(obj.toString()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could simplify the signature even more to use only one generic type: `public static <E extends Number> void parseCollection(Collection<?> src, Collection<E> dest, Class<E> clazz)`

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak thanks for pointing that out. Indeed its even simpler.

Comment: @SimY4 : Thank you for help... It worked...But I was wondering what was wrong with that super keyword.I'm sorry if the question seems to be meaningless,since I'm new to the java, felt like I should ask

Comment: Because dest is not Collection<? super Number>. Try List<Number> dest = new ArrayList<Number>();

Answer (score 0):

Your method is right but parameters are wrong. You have  in definition, but Long when you call the method. Try this :

>

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<String> src = new HashSet<String>();
    src.add("1");
    src.add("2");
    src.add("3");
    src.add("4");

    List<Number> dest = new ArrayList<Number>();
    parseCollection(src, dest, Long.class);// exception
    System.out.println(dest);
}
```